# Which one is better of domain object modeling in DDD?

Tags: orm, ado.net, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Please considering we are working for an HR related application construction, here we need to model our domain objects about department and employee.I'm wondering about whether domain object should be modeled with nested aggregate, especially nested in itself.

I'm trying to consider two different styles like the followings:

Solution #01, model employee with nested aggregate.

```
public class Employee : BusinessObject, IEmployee
{
     IList<IEmployee> ManagedStaffs { get; set;}
     IEmployee Supervisor { get; set;}
}
```

So we can use it as:

```
var emp = empRepository.Get(1);
// dot accessors
var numberOfPeople = emp.Supervisor.ManagedStaffs[0].ManagedStaffs.Count;
```

Solution #2, model employee without nested aggregate.

```
public class Employee : BusinessObject, IEmployee
{
    //without nested aggregate
}

public class Supervisor : Employee, ISupervisor
{
    IList<IEmployee> ManagedStaffs { get; set; }
}
```

So we can use it as:

```
var emp1 = empRepository.Get(1);
// GetManagedStaffs needs a parameter which is a ISupervisor
var empList1 = empRepository.GetManagedStaffs(emp1.Supervisor);
var empList2 = empRepository.GetManagedStaffs(empList[0]);
var numberOfPeople = empList2.Count;
```

If we want to persistence the domain objects without ORM, just pure ADO.NET, solution #2 looks much better.

If we want to use dot accessor in Solution #1, an transparent ORM framework need to be introductd, and lazy loading is welcome due to recursively nested aggregate.

I think the key point here to determine which one is the better solution is based on how to handle nested aggregate.

May I have your suggestion? or I have something need to be corrected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution is much better.

At first aggregates should be small. Usually not all operations require all aggregate components. If aggregate will be large - all its parts would be loaded into the memory, it would be harder to implement persistence logic for such aggregate, queries to the database will be more complex (Obviously persistence operations would make huge performance impact for large aggregates). You want to mitigate these impacts by lazy loading features of ORM but lazy loading requires more attention and control - you should exactly know what and when is loaded. Also from the point of performance it is better to load all aggregate by single query than by several queries like in lazy load.

Second, usage of the first scenario violates the Law of Demeter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). From this point #2 scenario usage is cleaner.

Comment: OK, It's really helpful for me to understand LoD, I missed its core concept before, and just for looking up a convenience way for data binding as programing gramma level sugar, i.e. <% # foo.bar.bla.bla.SomePropertyOrCollection %>.

Comment: Here is a useful article about LoD - http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/ Also there is a difference between domain objects and view models. View model is not intended to interact with other objects, it is used just for data representation. LoD is important when objects interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

#Solution 2 is nice. There is a nice "is-a" relationship between supervisor and employee. But this relationship is going to introduce coupling problems in the future. You change Employee i am afraid supervisor is also going to get affected. Another solution could be to favor "Composition over inheritance" as well as that of #solution 1. Decision is yours